# Format a link of a class in a div with an id

Tags: css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a link that is in a div, and the div has an id of sidebar-left.  I want to make it a different color when the link has the class current_page_item.  I have other links on the page (that are not in the div) that I do not want this formatting to apply to.

I have tried several different versions of the following code with no luck:

```
#sidebar-left.current_page_item a {
    color: #00b0f0;
}
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: this looks correct. Reproduced [on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mzv7d/). ensure you have no spelling mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
#sidebar-left .current_page_item a {
    color: #00b0f0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  That did the trick!  I thought I tried that, but I must have missed that version.